# How to join to inner query and calculate column based on different groupings?

Tags: sql, join

I have a table that contains data about a series of visits to shops. 
The raw data for these visits can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1mR_rZbvW1yS2k1eVg5TWFNc00/view?usp=sharing).

My main table will have 1 row per Country, and will use something along the lines of:

```
Select Distinct o.Country from OtherTable as o
```

I need to add a new column to my main table, that uses the following calculation:

> "Avg Visits by User" = (Sum of (No. Call IDs / No. unique User IDs)
>   for each day) / No. unique of days (based on Actual Start) for the
>   row.

I have formed this additional select statement to get the number of calls and users by day - but I am struggling to join this to my main table:

```
Select DATEPART(DAY, c.ActualStart) As 'Day',
CAST(CAST(COUNT(c.CallID) AS DECIMAL (5,1))/CAST(COUNT(Distinct c.UserID) AS DECIMAL (5,1)) AS DECIMAL (5,1)) as 'Value' from CallInfo as c
where (c.Status = 3)) 
Group by DATEPART(DAY, c.ActualStart)
```

For the country GB, I would expect to come to the see the following output:

```
Day    Calls  Users  Calls / Users
13-Jun  29     8     3.625
14-Jun  31     7     4.428571429
```

So, in my main table, the calculation for my new column would be:

> 8.053571 / 2

Therefore, if I somehow add this to my table I would expect the following output:

```
Country  Unique Days   Sum of Calls/Users for each day)   Final Calc
GB          2          8.053571429                        4.026785714
```

I have tried adding this as a join, but I don't know how to join this to my main table. I could for example join on Call Id - but this would require the addition of a callID column in my inner query, and this would mean that the values are incorrect.

Comment: What RDMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? Please tag it.

Comment: SQL Server - I couldn't tag that as I don't have enough points apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to make calculations by day and after that make calculations by country. The result SQL query can be like this:

```
-- Make calculation by country, from the subquery
SELECT Country, UniqueDays = count(TheDay), CallsUserPerDay = sum(CallsPerUser),
       FinalCalc = sum(CallsPerUser) / cast(count(TheDay) as DECIMAL)
  FROM (
        -- SUBQUERY: Make calculations by day
        SELECT c.Country, c.ActualStart as TheDay,
               Calls = COUNT(c.CallID),
               Users = COUNT(Distinct c.UserID),
               COUNT(c.CallID)
               /CAST(COUNT(Distinct c.UserID) AS DECIMAL) as CallsPerUser
          FROM CallInfo as c
         WHERE (c.Status = 3)
         GROUP BY c.Country, c.ActualStart
        ) data
 GROUP BY Country
```

**Note:** I avoid use precission on DECIMAL casting to avoid rounding on final result.

Comment: I have updated my initial main query, to reflect the fact that the main data can be linked to a different table. So Ideally I need to include my inner query in a join or something - i'm just not sure how to join to my main table. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: I would like to add though, that this is actually really helpful for something else I am currently working on.

Comment: Can you provide the schema? Anyway, you only need to join your `OtherTable`to `CallInfo` (In your samble `c.Country = o.Country`) and group by every field not in an aggregate function